# Paste formula into new row in excel using C# using get_Range

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel, vsto, add-in

```
1 A  B  C   D    E   F
2          =D1  =E1   
3           X    x
```

Some of the cells in row 3 are blank, i want for perticular range("D3","E3") formula to be pasted from row 2

plz do needful,
thanking you...

Comment: LOL......are u gonna accept answers??

Answer (score 1):

use the `Value2` of the range to get access to the actual formula per cell.

you can iterate over the range cells using `foreach (Range c in Source_Range.Cells)` (assuming `Source_Range` is D3:E3 cells.